# How to strip the Prometheus response content in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, prometheus

I'm trying to implement Prometheus client on Django App. But, the output I get is invalid which is why Prometheus server is unable to parse the metrics.

Here is my Prometheus API View

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from prometheus_client import (
    multiprocess,
    CollectorRegistry,
    generate_latest,
    CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST,
)


class PrometheusAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        registry = CollectorRegistry()
        multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
        return (
            Response(
                generate_latest(registry),
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST,
            )
        )
```

and here is the URL Pattern

```py
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^metrics/', PrometheusAPIView.as_view()),
    ]
```

---

When I curl the `metrics/` endpoint, I get this

```
❯ curl localhost:8000/metrics/                                                                                      
"# HELP model_latency Multiprocess metric\n# TYPE model_latency histogram\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"10.0\"} 4.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.1\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.005\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_sum{app=\"app-name\"} 7.6447835210005906\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.25\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.75\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"7.5\"} 4.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"5.0\"} 4.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.5\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"2.5\"} 3.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.075\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.01\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.05\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"+Inf\"} 4.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"1.0\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_bucket{app=\"app-name\",le=\"0.025\"} 0.0\nmodel_latency_count{app=\"app-name\"} 4.0\n# HELP log_count_total Multiprocess metric\n# TYPE log_count_total counter\nlog_count_total{app=\"app-name\",level=\"INFO\"} 8.0\n"
```

But, what I expect is like below

```
# HELP model_latency Multiprocess metric
# TYPE model_latency histogram
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="10.0"} 2.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.1"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.005"} 0.0
model_latency_sum{app="app-name"} 4.431863597000756
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.25"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.75"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="7.5"} 2.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="5.0"} 2.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.5"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="2.5"} 1.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.075"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.01"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.05"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="+Inf"} 2.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="1.0"} 0.0
model_latency_bucket{app="app-name",le="0.025"} 0.0
model_latency_count{app="app-name"} 2.0
# HELP log_count_total Multiprocess metric
# TYPE log_count_total counter
log_count_total{app="app-name",level="INFO"} 4.0
```

---

So, it's basically that I need to strip the output I'm getting without those escape characters.

I tried to strip in the response like below but that's throwing an error

```py
return (
            Response(
                generate_latest(registry),
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST,
            )
            .__str__()
            .strip()
```

How do I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to / have to use the `APIView` base class for your handler then you need to make use of the `StaticHTMLRenderer` so the Prometheus metrics data isn't escaped.

```
from rest_framework.renderers import StaticHTMLRenderer

class PrometheusAPIView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = [StaticHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        registry = CollectorRegistry()
        multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
        return (
            Response(
                generate_latest(registry),
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST,
            )
        )
```

You can also consider ditching `APIView` altogether and use a standard Django handler:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def metrics(request):
    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    return HttpResponse(
        generate_latest(registry),
        content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)



urlpatterns = [
    path('metrics/', metrics),
]
```